# flv img does not appear <fb:flv src="" ..... img='img url' ...>

Tags: facebook

I am developing a facebook application to show some flv videos.videos are shown but, the preview img does not appear this is my code:

```
<fb:flv src='http://mobimediaworld.com/flv/3.flv' width='180' height='150' title='Mekawy' color='#FFBB00' salign='r' img='http://www.gcmob.com/Images/Media/PreviewFrame/27.png' scale='showall'/>
```

can anybody help me, pleas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry buddy fb:flv not working anymore dont know why.

use this:

```
<fb:swf 
    swfbgcolor="000000" 
    imgstyle="border-width:3px; border-color:white;" 
    swfsrc='http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxxx' 
    imgsrc='http://img.youtube.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxx/2.jpg' 
    width='340' height='270' />
```